# How can I install composer packages with drush make?

Tags: drush, deployment, composer, 8

How does one include composer package in a drush make file?

The more general answer, the better. There's already a composer drush module allowing drush dl to handle composer packages, but that requires a shell command for every dependency.

Given our future use of Symfony, composer and other Symfony bundles is likely to become more important in the future.

Comment: I think this is a feature request for the Drush issue queue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use yoursite.make to download the Drupal module and composer.json for composer.

There is the [Composer](http://drupal.org/project/composer) module that integrates Composer with Drush.

I hope that soon .make is going to disappear, replaced by composer.json; for that to come true, some issues need to be resolved, such as version number.

Composer packages are stored in the git repository; you can't use a composer package, but you can download the code. For example, for https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony you can use the following.

```
libraries[symfony][download][type] = "git"
libraries[symfony][download][url] = " https://github.com/symfony/symfony.git"
libraries[symfony][destination] = "lib/symfony/"
```

Composer can build stuff recursively; of course, this will not work here.

See: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush/plain/docs/make.txt

Their is also https://github.com/composer/installers than can do the invert (install drupal module with composer).

Comment: Is that meant to say my question cannot be answered? (Yes, composer files for drush sounds like an interesting feature)

Comment: Yes it can't be answered. It will make no sens to "port" composer into drush make (at least for my point of view). I edited my answer to give some kind of workaround.

Comment: Actually, (ab)using the libraries syntax seems like an entirely valid workaround. +1.